# How many ways are there to make 50 cents of change using pennies, nickels, dimes, and/or quarters?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the question and that I could count all of the combinations but how would I go about finding it without counting every combination? My reasoning is that this could be calculated by separating the coins used into separate cases and then finding adding up all the cases in the end, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with case-wise anaylsis; if I were writing a computer program that's how I'd do it. It may help to stagger the cases in terms of decreasing value (e.g. first the number of quarters, and within that, first the number of dimes, etc.). Smarter approaches will infer patterns from this type of reasoning.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271319/on-the-number-of-ways-to-make-50n-cents-out-of-pennies-nickels-dimes-and-qua may be useful.

Comment: If you are familiar with generating functions, you want the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the expansion of $$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots)(1 + x^5 + x^{10} + x^{15} + \cdots)(1 + x^{10} + x^{20} + x^{30} +  \cdots)(1 + x^{25} + x^{50} + \cdots)$$ where the first factor counts the contributions of pennies, the second factor counts the contributions of nickels, the third factor counts the contributions of dimes, and the fourth factor counts the contributions of quarters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, but then you have to find (or know) a way to get that coefficient without doing as much work as it would take to just write out all the possibilities.